# Redis IDistributedCache is not showing up in ElasticApm

Tags: c#, redis, elastic-apm

currently for my application. I have ElasticAPM setup. I would like to enhance it so I can start seeing redis within Elastic APM as well.

May I ask if anyone has had success with setting up IDistributedCache with Elastic APM?

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = redisConnection;
});
```

I tried also adding this bit of code suggested here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/setup-stackexchange-redis.html

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(provider =>
{
    var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redis);
    connection.UseElasticApm();
    return connection;
});
```

But unfortunately I am still unable to see redis in Elastic APM when tracing. If I may get assistance on how to get ElasticAPM working with IDistributedCache, would greatly appreciate it.